# Create a Weeknumber

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I would like to have my column Weenumber containing weeknumber based on the input data column A2

The problem is that when I use weeknumber (in Swedish) I do not retrieve a weeknumber in the column Weeknumber.

Today, I'm using excel 2010

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the format of the B col to General

Edit:

Here is a screenshot in GNUMERIC (sorry it's not excell but I use it only at work).

The problem is the same, and the solution works fine.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: Select the wrong formatted cell. In the ribbon on the top on your sheet just right of the range you clipped for the screenshot (so right of the 'Radbryt text' button is a dropdown menu. Select 'General' or what is corresponding in Swedish.